# ' ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence ' when using plt.show() in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVwX.png)I'm learning how to using python to draw some 3D pictures. 
When I typing `plt.show()`, there will be an error.

```py
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

However, I have tried run it on IDLE and it didn't have an error.
What should I do to fix this problem when using PyCharm, really appreciate for helping.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


x = np.linspace(-6 * np.pi, 6 * np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.cos(x)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


ax.plot(x, y, z)


plt.show()
```

I tried it in Python Console, only when I run `plt.show()` there will be an error.

```
[<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D at 0x111b09c88>]
plt.show()
/Users/harry./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:1743: UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so its results might be incorrect.
  warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-1eb00ff78cf2>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "/Users/harry./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 253, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 27, in __call__
    manager.show(**kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 99, in show
    self.canvas.show()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend/backend_interagg.py", line 64, in show
    self.figure.tight_layout()
  File "/Users/harry./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1753, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "/Users/harry./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 326, in get_tight_layout_figure
    max_nrows = max(nrows_list)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: I get no error on my machine when I run your code.
Can you try to do `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart` and re-run your code?

Comment: @Eskapp thank you for answering. I tried to restart but it did not work... any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you precise the matplotlib version that you are using? `import matplotlib` and then `matplotlib.__version__`. Also which vwersion of Pycharm are you using (number and whether it is Community or Pro)

Comment: @Eskapp  The version of matplotlib is 2.0.2 and the version of PyCharm is ''PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Professional Edition)'' using educational liences

Comment: Go to `File -> Tools -> Python Scientific` and try to play with the box `Show plots in tool window`

Comment: @Eskapp yes I tried to do so, but still has error `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`